# Compile error when using the new mmlight with a preprocessing script

Tags: mmenu

I've moved from the now deprecated jquery.mmenu (available at http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) to mmlight (https://mmenujs.com/).
Same author, different version of the script, with the latter being more modern and short in size between the other things.

While using the new version in conjunction with a static site generator that has a pre-processing routine to compress Javascript I got an error that I was able to pin down to the line that contains the `=>`

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
```

Regrettably the error from the verbose is not helpful when it says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc ())
JS_Parse_Error.get ((execjs):3538:621)
(execjs):4060:48
(execjs):1:102
Object.<anonymous> ((execjs):1:120)
Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:738:30)
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:749:10)
Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:630:32)
tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:570:12)
Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:3)
Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to forward?

Is there any chance to rewrite the routine as a custom prototype or similar?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the issue is the new ES6 and Uglifier that doesn't support it in full yet as stated here https://github.com/lautis/uglifier

The workaround is to activate the compressor as per their recommendation.